# Problems in calling facebook login dialogue in android using facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
   if (access_token != null) {
      facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
   }

   if (expires != 0) {
      facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
   }

   if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
      facebook.authorize(this,
         new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
         new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
               // Function to handle cancel event
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
               // Function to handle complete event
               // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
               AsyncCallFacebookCredentials task1 = new AsyncCallFacebookCredentials();
               task1.execute();
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
               editor.putString("LoginStatus", "on");
               editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
               Log.e("AccessToken",facebook.getAccessToken());
               fbAccessToken_edit.putString("fbAccessToken", facebook.getAccessToken());
               fbAccessToken_edit.commit();
               editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
               editor.commit();
               Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError error) {
              Log.e("Error",error.ToString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
               Log.e("Error",error.ToString());
            }

         });
   }

}
```

i am using above function in two activities, two activities have exactly same code as above, but in one activity it works perfectly but in other activity the login dialogue takes too much time to appear and after appearing if i enter credentials and press login button nothing happens.

Comment: are you using SDK for facebook??

Comment: i have found the issue today, i am using above function in the activity which was called by startactivityforresult that is the problem, if call the activity as just StartActivity() then above code working fine, but i need to use startactivityforresult because i need to write data back to calling activity